# How to add more than one fields in Like statement in SOQl?

Tags: soql, search

I am trying to search records based on the 3 fields whose are text fields,

I am getting with one text field like below, how can i achieve with 3 text fields data. How to modify code in Apex and also Visualforce page?

```
 object=[select name from object__c where Aadhar_ID__c Like :'%'+inputName+'%'];
```

Comment: can you please tell what are your three 3 text fields data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your other variables are `inputName2` and `inputName3` and the fields you want to check are `Aadhar_Id_2__c`, `Aadhar_Id_3__c`. Here's what your query must look like:

```
inputName = '%' + inputName + '%';
inputName2 = '%' + inputName2  + '%';
inputName3 = '%' + inputName3 + '%';
object=[select name from object__c where Aadhar_ID__c LIKE :inputName AND Aadhar_Id_2__c LIKE :inputName2 AND Aadhar_Id_3__c LIKE :inputName3];
```

Comment: @ Hi Martin, It is working fine, Thank you, But if the record don't have values in any one of 3 fields(In the DB),It is not displaying the record. I am trying to give OR inplace of AND but not getting.  How can we achieve this?

Comment: @RavindarAdmin If you want to check only if one value is matching, you have to use `OR` instead of `AND` like you said. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AND operator in the SOQL's WHERE clause.
For e.g. below SOQL retrieves accounts where BillingState contains 'Goa', SAP ID contains '0000' and account name contains the string 'Electricals'

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE BillingState LIKE '%Goa%' AND SAP_External_Id__c LIKE '%0000%' AND Name LIKE '%Electricals%'];
```

Comment: Hi, Bennie, Thanks for ur replay.  If i want to display the record to retreive the accounts where Billingstate contains 'Goa' or account name contains 'Electrical'. How can we query?